# Sending event to Event Hub from third party applications

Tags: events, crm, azure-eventhub

How do I send event from a third-party application like CREATIO to Azure Event Hub?
I had set up the event hub and shared access policies as well. Is there any option available in CREATIO to send the events directly to event hub? Or do we need to create an API to achieve the same? What's the best way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.
With Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CREATIO but strictly from an integration point of view, REST APIs are usually the simplest way to ensure compatibility with third-party services, especially ones where you don't have full control of.

If CREATIO allows you to have some custom code, you could leverage the Azure SDKs to connect directly to Azure Event Hubs. But if the port or protocol are blocked, HTTPS is usually your best bet.

You could create a super simple [Azure Function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) and leverage the [Event Hubs Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5) to create a simple endpoint to accept new events.